# gsutil stat bucket issue while Uploading

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to use the gsutil stat command to display object status for a subdirectory and got an error
`gsutil -q stat gs://my-bucket/my-object/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage uses a flat namespace to store objects in buckets.
While you can use slashes ("/") in object names to make it appear as if objects are in a hierarchical structure, **the gsutil stat command treats a trailing slash as part of the object name.**

For example, if you run the command gsutil -q stat gs://my-bucket/my-object/, gsutil looks up information about the object my-object/ (with a trailing slash), as opposed to operating on objects nested under my-bucket/my-object/. Unless you actually have an object with that name, the operation fails.

For subdirectory listing, use the gsutil ls instead.